# PerformancePoint Filters do not work (Sharepoint List as data source)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, dashboard-designer-2013

Tabular data source filter problem in PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer

Dear all,
Your suggestion on the following problem resolution will be highly appreciated.

SharePoint 2013, Analysis Services with SQL not configured.  PerfromancePoint dashboard is built using Sharepoint List as data source.  Four dashboard filters configurations shown below – neither one work:
1. Member Selection filter – error while deploying dashboard.
2a. Custom Table filter connected to Scorecard page – no filtering, but dashboard appearance is correct.
2b. Custom Table filter connected to Scorecard row – dashboard calculation is false, filterin works.
3. Custom Table filter connected to Scorecard page and row – same result as in 2b.

The simplest list made for demonstration purpose only (see below).  The filters behavior is similar using any other SharePoints lists.

[image: Sharepoint List used for this exercise]

Tabular data source is created in PP using secure store credentials (see below).  The filters behavior do not change while using the Unattended Service Account.

[image: PerformancePoint Tabular Data Source Created]

The scorecard is built using the simplest KPI.

[image: The scorecard used for this example]

---

CASE 1. Filter Member selection behavior.

Filter Member Selection is created as below.

[image: Filter Member Selection configuration]

The dashboard 1 is created connecting filter 1 and the scorecard 1

[image: Dashboard 1 connection]

Dashboard 1 is deployed to SharePoint with an error.

[image]

---

CASE 2a.  Filter Custom Table

Filter 2 is created based on custom table.

[image: Custom Table filter configuration]

The dashboard 2 is created connecting filter 2 “Title” value and the page of the same scorecard 1.

[image: Dashboard 2 connections]

I deploy the dashboard 2 to Sharepoint, seems correct

[image: Dashboard 2 deployed in SharePoint]

I apply filter – it does not work, there is no changes in the scorecard.

[image: Filter on dashboard 2 does not work]

---

CASE 2b.  The same Filter 2 based on the Custom Table.

I create the dashboard 3 connecting ‘Title’ value of Filter 2 and the Row of the scorecard 1.

[image: Dashboard 3 connections with Custom Table filter]

I deploy the dashboard 3 – completely false result.

[image: Dashboard 3 deployed with error]

Applying filter – rows are filtered, but the result is wrong.

[image: Filter applied to dashboard 3 - filters but the contest is wrong!]

---

CASE 3.  The same Filter 2 based on the Custom Table has two connections to the same scorecard 1.  Title column is connected to 1) Page and 2) Row of the scorecard.

[image: Dashboard 4 connection to Scorecard Page]

[image: Dashboard 4 connection to Scorecard Row]

The result is identical to the case 2b.

[image: Dashboard 4 with two Filter connections to Scorecard]

Could anybody say where we should look to correct the situation?  We are at the level of very basic SharePoint / PerformancePoint functionality and can not move on! Thanks all in advance!

Inna